# CGAffineTransformScale + Gestures

Tags: objective-c, ios, transform, cgaffinetransform, gestures

I have a problem.
There is a uiview, which is controlled by gestures (can be moved horizontally).
And while this uiview is small, everything is OK.

After scaling it using CGAffineTransformScale the strangeness starts:
Pan began working odd - became not very sensitive.
So in a larger state, I can move my finger in the range of 1.5 cm before the PAN start working.
After that, everything works (UIView drags by finger), but not very smoothly.

I think that something is increased after CGAffineTransformScale with the view, that is responsible for the gestures.
If I reduce the view back, the gestures start working as it should.

Please help!
Thank you!

// transition

```
[UIView transitionWithView:pagesView   
                  duration:0.25  
                   options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut + UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction + UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState
                animations:^{

                    pagesView.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(pagesView.transform, kResize, kResize);

                }   
                completion:^(BOOL finished){


                }];
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're asking the pan gesture recognizer for its translation in the view, and the view has been scaled to twice its natural size, then the movement of your finger is divided by two to compute the translation.  Presumably that's not what you want.

Ask the pan gesture recognizer for its translation in a view that has *not* been scaled.  I assume that your scaled view has a non-transformed superview.  Try using this as your gesture recognizer's action:

```
- (IBAction)pan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)panner {
    UIGestureRecognizerState state = panner.state;
    if (state != UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged && state != UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
        return;
    UIView *movingView = panner.view;
    UIView *referenceView = movingView.superview;
    CGPoint offset = [panner translationInView:referenceView];
    [panner setTranslation:CGPointZero inView:referenceView];
    CGPoint center = movingView.center;
    center.x += offset.x;
    center.y += offset.y;
    movingView.center = center;
}
```